# Bitwise comparison of any structure

Tags: c++, bitwise

What I tried to do is compare arbitrary structures independent of the `==` operator implementation.

```
template<typename T>
bool bitWiseCompare(T a, T b)
{
  size_t size = sizeof(T) / sizeof(char);
  char* array_a = (char*)(&a);
  char* array_b = (char*)(&b);
  for(size_t i = 0; i<size; i++)
  {
    if(array_a[i] != array_b[i])
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: return 0==memcmp(&a,&b,sizeof(T));

Comment: Thats very dangerous. Only really useful for buffers which is why we use `operator==` normally.

Comment: @Darius, you do know that `sizeof` reports in units of `char`, making `sizeof (char)` equal to 1 *by definition*, don't you?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This comparison can fail if there are any padding bytes within `T`, as those extra bytes are not initialized to any particular value.

Another source of failure can come from inheritance.  If one of the objects is part of a larger class (`T` is being used as a base class) with virtual functions, the vtable pointers can be different if `a` and `b` are part of different class hierarchies.  Virtual inheritance of base classes of `T` can also cause problems.

`sizeof(char)` is always 1, so there is no need to divide by it.

Since you're only reading from your parameters, you should take them by `const &T` to avoid making unnecessary copies.

Comment: In other words, this comparison can only handle POD types nicely.

Comment: @bipll: while it'll work for POD types on most modern machines, it's not really even certain to work for them. Even a plain `int` is allowed to contain padding bytes.

Comment: Ok, there should be 'at most' rather than 'only'. :)

Answer (score 6):

The C++ way isn't necessarily to stay away of such things as bit comparisons, but rather to do it in the most obvious way possible -by that I mean that your code should look dangerous and explicit at the same time. You have tools for this at your disposal: namespaces, ugly looking casts and algorithms:

```
#include <algorithm>
namespace unsafe {
    template <typename T>
    constexpr auto begin(const T& item) {
        return reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&item);
    }
    template <typename T>
    constexpr auto end(const T& item) {
        return reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&item)+sizeof(T);
    }
    template <typename T>
    auto bitwise_equal(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
        return std::equal(begin(lhs), end(lhs), // will become constexpr with C++20
                          begin(rhs), end(rhs));
    }
}
```

So it won't look innocuous when you use it:

```
int main() {
    auto a = 125.5;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << unsafe::bitwise_equal(a, a);
}
```

A few further remarks:

- bitwise_compare isn't the most accurate name for the function, since `compare` is traditionally reserved for functions returning order (-1, 0, 1), and not only equality.
- providing `begin()` and `end()` isn't necessary, since `begin(item)+sizeof(T)` is as correct, and probably as readable a replacement, but aesthetic reasons are sometimes enough
- `std::equal` is set to become `constexpr` with the new standard, meaning this C++'s style implementation might become more efficient than the `memcmp` implementation given compile-time values.
- it's generally better to use the four-argument versions of algorithms over two ranges; in this case it is obviously redundant since the length of the two arguments are by construction equal, but then consistency is a virtue.
- reusing `algorithm`s is a good way to avoid dumb but frequent errors one would make with a raw loop,

for instance:

```
auto  pa = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a);
for (auto pb = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&b); pb != pb+sizeof(T); ++pb) // oops!
    // ...
```

Comment: Do you have a preference in `end()` for repeating the cast, rather than just writing `begin() + sizeof item`?  If so, consider explaining your reasoning.  Similarly, is there any benefit to including the fourth argument to `std::equal()`?

Comment: @TobySpeight: what is the policy, editing the post or adding explanations in a comment?

Comment: It's better to edit your answer to improve the explanation, as comments can be lost, or crowded out by other comments.  The only edits we don't allow here on CR are edits to code in Questions after any answers are received (so that the answers aren't invalidated).

Comment: Perhaps adding a ref-comparison first makes sense? `return &lhs == &rhs || std::equal(...);`

Comment: @bipll: not sure about that, because it is a pessimization whenever `lhs` and `rhs` aren't the same object, and because the client might well test this on his own unless he knows the details of our implementation.

Comment: While `std::equal` is set to become `constexpr`, `reinterpret_cast` isn't. So this won't become faster than `memcmp` anytime soon.

I wonder if it would make sense to create a small wrapper, `byte_view<T>` which would allow the use of the ranges proposal. This would obviate the need to use `std::equal` with iterators.